# SWIFT 2 - Impossibile to pass value from UICollectionViewController to UICollectionViewCell. Found NIL

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to pass a value from a `UiCollectionViewController` to a `UICollectionViewCell`.
I have created a custom `UICollectionViewCell` connected to the CellView in my storyboard. Then I have created a UILabel IBOutlet.

When I try to send a value to my UICollectionViewCell class I always get the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

which is coming from the line:

```
videoCell.nameUsrVideo.text = "TEST"
```

Also I cannot see any object that I had in the cell

Any Idea Why?

UiCollectionViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

            collectionView!.registerClass(videoCellClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell")

    }

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let videoCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("VideoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! videoCellClass

        videoCell.nameUsrVideo.text = "TEST"

        return videoCell
    }
```

UICollectionViewCell:

```
class videoCellClass: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameUsrVideo: UILabel!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {



        super.init(frame: frame)



    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the line

```
collectionView!.registerClass(videoCellClass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "VideoCell")
```

because it's replacing the cell registration from the storyboard, which has all of the outlet definitions, with a simple class registration. That means the cell won't be unarchived from the storyboard when you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` and none of the outlets will exist.

Comment: if I remove that line I get the error:    fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented:

Comment: That's because you've implemented that method to throw that exception. you can't do that...

Comment: init(coder:) is the init method called when you create a view from storyboard.. Do you write the code yourself?